# How to reference a local Property once the DataContext is set to an Ancestor win WPF/Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some UserControl fields which provide a textbox inside of a user control.  I'm referencing the UserControl as:

```
<UserControl 
DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

I'm setting it to this because my UserControls are in a view model that share some common commands, etc so I can bind those properties to my outer ViewModel:

This is working as desired.  The issue is that each UserControl has their own view model in order to track things like a Value property:

```
<UserControl 
IsInDesignMode="{Binding IsInDesignMode}" 
Text="{Binding Value}" 
DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

If I use:

```
<UserControl 
IsInDesignMode="{Binding IsInDesignMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
ControlText="{Binding DataContext.Value}"  />
```

or

```
<UserControl 
IsInDesignMode="{Binding DataContext.IsInDesignMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
ControlText="{Binding DataContext.Value}" 
 />
```

The ControlText binds properly to the UserControl's viewmodel's Value, so that seems like the right approach, but the IsInDesignMode won't bind to the same view/viewmodel as it does when I have the DataContext= from the first version.

Comment: You could name your `UserControl` and reference it by name. `{Binding ElementName=NameOfTheUserControl, Path=DataContext.Value}`

Comment: Never do what you did. This is why. Rethink your binding strategy. If you need to bind to something on a parent view, use RelativeSource for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated my question.